# Merge two tables to one using phpmyad

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has this format

```
id     value1     value2      value3
1         3         0.8          4
1         4         7.4          9
1         3          0           12
1         4          5           3
1         0          21          3 
1         0.1        42          3
1         2          21          5 
2         11         32          9
2         32          4          9
2         54          4          2
2         32          45         3
2         21          4          3
3         30          3          8
3         42          3          10
3         42          4          21
3         31          4          31
df         50          0          12
df        12          44         11
```

I want to calculate the sum for every unique id for every value and also the value3/value2.

Here is an example of what I take  at the end.

```
id  value1  value2  value3  value3/value2
1   16.1    97.2    39  0.401
2   150 89  26  0.29
3   145 14  70  5
df  62  44  93  2.11
```

How can I do it with MySQL and save them to a new table?

Comment: How is this a merge problem? It looks more like an aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, 
       sum(value1) as value1,
       sum(value2) as value2,
       sum(value3) as value3,
       sum(value3) / sum(value2) as value2_3
from your_table
group by id
```

You can put that in another table like this

```
insert into new_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select id, 
       sum(value1) as value1,
       sum(value2) as value2,
       sum(value3) as value3,
       sum(value3) / sum(value2) as value2_3
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: How can I save the results to a new table?

Comment: `insert into new_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) select id, sum(value1) ....`